# Can I recover word file from computer?

Tags: file-recovery

I did cut and paste a ms word file from computer to usb drive and lost the drive. Is there anyway to recover the file from computer?

Thanks.

Comment: All the recovery softwares that I found are to recover the deleted files within the PC. Couldnt find anything for cut and transfer to usb, I could give a shot. Didnt do much on PC except rebooting twice

Answer (score 1):

You can try recovery tools to get it back. Do a google search for "I accidentally deleted a file, recovery tool" and you should find some software to lead you in the right direction. Just make sure to read review first as to not download any malware.

This will work so long as any new changes made to your hard drive didn't overwrite the location in which the word doc was physically stored. For this reason, you should not do anything else to your PC until you recover that file. Absolutely avoid installing any application (aside from the recovery tool) and avoid and file transfers. As long as you didn't overwrite the file by making too many changes to your system, it should be recoverable using file recovery tools.

Comment: recuva, test disk are good programs!

Comment: tried with recuva. nothing showed up

Comment: How long has it been since you cut and pasted?

Comment: 2 weeks. didnt used the computer

Comment: If you used the application to recovery it and it's not showing up as a recoverable item, then you unfortunately can't recover it. I'm assuming you never saved it to any online storage solution like Dropbox or one drive?

Comment: No, I havent saved it anywhere. That file wasnt created on the computer. I was transferred to the desktop from the usb and cut n pasted it back. I am not sure if it makes any difference.

Comment: I think at this point you are out of luck. Recovery didn't work and you lost the USB drive. Not sure what else to tell you.